# glreadpixels with FBO attachment

Tags: c++, opengl, fbo

Ok, so I have this FBO with a depth buffer and 4 color attachments. I want to read the dept buffer at the place where I hold the cursor and a value from the fourth color attachment. I don't seem to manage any of the two. 
I've wrote this class :

```
class Picker3D{
    public:
bool useAtachment;
GLenum  atachment;
float PickerLastSignature;
point3f PickerLastPos;

Picker3D( bool useAtachment = true , GLenum atachment = GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT3 ) : useAtachment(useAtachment) , atachment(atachment) {

}

void SetObjectSignature( float signature , GLSL_Prog prog ){
    glUniform1f( glGetUniformLocation( prog.PR , "Signature" ) , signature );
}

float getSignature( float x , float y , float height ){
    glGetError();
    if( useAtachment )
        glReadBuffer( atachment );

    cout << " Error message1 : " << glGetError() << endl ;

    float *pixels = new float[4];
    glReadPixels( x , height - y , 1 , 1 , GL_RGB , GL_FLOAT , pixels );
    PickerLastSignature = pixels[1];

    cout << " Error message2 : " << glGetError() << endl ;

    return PickerLastSignature;
}

point3f get3DPosition( float x , float y , float height ){
    //glReadBuffer( GL_DEPTH_ATTACHMENT );

    double depth;
    glReadPixels( x , y , 1 , 1 , GL_DEPTH_COMPONENT , GL_FLOAT , &depth );

    cout << depth << endl;

    int viewport[4];
    float *modelview;
    double projection[16];
    double ModelView[16];

    modelview = mat4f::GetTopMatrix().returnTransposedMatrix().returnFloatArray();
    for( int i = 0 ; i < 16 ; i++ ){
        ModelView[i] = modelview[i];
    }

    glGetDoublev(GL_PROJECTION_MATRIX, projection);
    glGetIntegerv(GL_VIEWPORT, viewport);

    double x1 , y1 , z1;

    gluUnProject( x , height - y , depth , ModelView  , projection , viewport , &x1 , &y1 , &z1 );

    PickerLastPos = point3f( x1 , y1 , z1 );
    return PickerLastPos;
}
```

};

and I use it like so

// in main loop

```
BindFrameBuffer(); 
drawStuff(); 
Picker.get3DPosition( x , y , height );
Picker.getSignature( x , y , height );
UnbindBuffer();
drawSecondPass(); 
endDrawSecondPass();
// check Values of PickerLastPos and PickerLastSignature 
SwapBuffers();
```

the depth is not changing altrough it is working on the screen and the getSignature gives error 1282( invalid operation, I think ) at the line with glReadBuffer.

the main loop is :

```
               glClear( GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT | GL_STENCIL_BUFFER_BIT );

            /// deferred pass

            DefFBO->drawFBO();
            GeometryShader.UseNow();

            glClear( GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT | GL_STENCIL_BUFFER_BIT );

            // load the view matrix and set the camera
            cam.camera_set();
            cam.camera_get( GeometryShader );

            // load identity for model matrix
            mat4f::LoadIdentity();

            /// Geometry Drawing

            mat4f::PushMatrix();

                mat4f::Translate( 0 , 0 , -10 );
                Picker.SetObjectSignature( 1.0f , GeometryShader );
                T90.obj_rend( GeometryShader );
                Picker.SetObjectSignature( 2.0f , GeometryShader );
                Town.obj_rend( GeometryShader );

            mat4f::PopMatrix();

            Picker.get3DPosition( Window.Mouse->mouse_x , Window.Mouse->mouse_y , Window.Height );

            /// setting the deferred read from buffer part

            // last read from  framebuffer
            Picker.getSignature( Window.Mouse->mouse_x , Window.Mouse->mouse_y , Window.Height );

            // unbind FBO
            DefFBO->readFBO();

            // use fragment shader, for lights and for post processing
            FragmentShader.UseNow();

            // send windows width and height and bind multiple textures
            DefFBO->send_to_GLSL( FragmentShader.PR );

            // send view matrix to the shader
            cam.camera_get( FragmentShader );

            glDepthMask(GL_FALSE);
            glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);

            glUniform3f( glGetUniformLocation( FragmentShader.PR , "CameraPosition" ) , cam.x , cam.y , cam.z );

            /// final draw
            DefFBO->sendGlobalLight( FragmentShader , point3f( 0 , 1 , 0 ) , point3f( 0.3 , 0.3 , 0.3 ) , point3f( 0.9 , 0.9 , 0.9 ) );

            cout << Picker.PickerLastPos << endl;

            DefFBO->end_read();

            glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);
            glDepthMask(GL_TRUE);
```

Comment: Just wanted to point out something I noticed in one of your commented out lines: `//glReadBuffer( GL_DEPTH_ATTACHMENT )`. That will not work, the read buffer set with that command is a color buffer so really only FRONT/BACK/LEFT/RIGHT (or some combination of these) and `GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENTi` are valid values. There is too much missing code to comment on anything else though; the actual FBO setup (e.g. what is attached where) is not even listed. `GL_INVALID_OPERATION` leads me to believe you have the wrong FBO bound, or it does not actually have something attached to `GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT3`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that I had to bind the fbo for reading for geting data out of it, as @Andon pointed out. I was binding with GL_DRAW_FRAMEBUFFER.

Comment: Yes, that's the idea behind separating `GL_FRAMEBUFFER` into `GL_DRAW_FRAMEBUFFER` and `GL_READ_FRAMEBUFFER`. It allows you to control independently which frame buffer you draw to, and which frame buffer you read from. Being able to do this is crucial for operations that both read from and write to frame buffers, most notably `glBlitFramebuffer()`. But it also applies to other read operations, like `glReadPixels()`.